# 数値の合計を計算する方法について

Tags: ruby

結果の合計の方法について質問です。

```
num = 0
10.times do
  num += 1
  p num
end
```

上記を実行すると結果が1から10まで帰ってきますが、その1から10までの合計を出したいのですが上手い方法が思いつきません。
何か方法がありましたら教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございます！sumを別に作ってそこにnumを足していけば良かったんですね。

Comment: 1から10までの合計値という事でしたら、`(1..10).sum` という方法もあります。

Comment: いろいろな方法があるんですね！upto、downtoでも上手くいきました。本当にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「合計を求める用」の変数を用意し、その変数に数字を足し合わせていけばよさそうです。

```
num = 0
sum = 0
10.times do
    num += 1
    sum += num
    p num
end
p sum
```

Answer (score 3):

timesを使う場合、回数を取得出来るのでそれを利用すると変数を使わなくてもよさそうです。

```
sum = 0
10.times do |i|
    sum += i+1
    p i + 1
end
p sum
```

また1から10まで、というのを明確にしたい場合は`upto`を使うのも手かと思います。

```
sum = 0
1.upto(10) do |i|
    sum += i
    p i
end
p sum
```

逆の場合は`downto`というものもあります。

```
10.downto(1) do |i|
    p i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..10).reduce {|sum, i| sum + i }
```